# Ajax To PHP converter get value from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i need help, here my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstok.php?secretkey=123&sku=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Masukkan kode barang / SKU:</b></p>
<form> 
Kode Barang: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I need is:**

1. I want to hide this `"secretkey=123"` so visitor cannot see my secret key
2. when call `"xmlhttp.send();"` return the value and I want to convert it to php like example

   `$getxmlhttp = xmlhttp.send();`
3. when I type something it will be call function, but when I press enter that refresh, how to **disable** the enter or what the best suggestion for me.

**this is my site sample:**
http://stok.tk

for example type `"YI 067"`

Comment: to hide the `secretkey=123` part you need to use *post* ajax request

Comment: Whats secretkey=123 do? I changed it it makes no difference. If you want a CSRF token etc then use headers.

Comment: Ajax never hide value, you can check the values by console of browser. no matter it is `get` or `post`. Either encrypt the value or change the flow.

Comment: for 3, return false on the function called when the form submits to prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page.

Comment: @devsourav can u give me some code, i really dont understand

Comment: @devsourav : how you prevent values in post by ajax? They are still visible by console of browser.

Comment: Where is secretkey coming from and what is it supposed to be/do?

Comment: @urfusion you're right console will show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : You can't. The browser (and so the visitor) can always know wich page is called with wich URL and parameters

2 : You can't do it like that. You need to get the value of your request into `getstok.php` with the super global variables `$_GET['your var']`

3 : It's reloading the page because it's sending your form. By default it send it to the same page. Just remove your `<form>`

Comment: about No. 2 how to just call function php (not ajax) but send to ajax ?

Comment: how about add loading image when search ?